# Insert Node based on its Index in Into LinkedList

Tags: java

I've been working on project to insert a node based on its index into a linkedlist and if the the index of the node is == -1 insert it at the end.

This is my first shot at LinkedLists so Im not even sure If im connecting these things properly so any tips would really help.

I've been able to get the nodes into the list in order but after the first test case I get a null pointer Exception.

Here is my code

-------------------LinkedListClass---------------------

```
   package edu.wmich.cs1120.GudahWaleed.lab7.impl;

import edu.wmich.cs1120.lab7.interfaces.ICharNode;
import edu.wmich.cs1120.lab7.interfaces.IListCharNodes;

public class ListCharNodes implements IListCharNodes {

    private int length;
    private ICharNode lastNode;
    private ICharNode firstNode;

    public ListCharNodes() {
        firstNode = new CharNode();
        lastNode = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return firstNode == null;
    }

    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        ICharNode p = firstNode;
        while (p != null) {
            count++;
            p = p.getNext();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public ICharNode get_Symmetric(ICharNode node) {

        ICharNode temp = firstNode.getNext();

        for (int i = length / 2; i < length; i++) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }

        return temp;

    }

    @Override
    public ICharNode getFirstNode(ICharNode node) {

        return firstNode;

    }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {

        return length;
    }

    public void insertCharNode(ICharNode node) {

        int index = node.getIndex();

        if (index == -1) {

            insertCharNodeAtEnd(node);

        }

        else if (firstNode.getIndex() == node.getIndex()) {
            node.setNext(firstNode.getNext());
            firstNode = node;
            return;
        }

        else if (index == 0) {
            node.setNext(firstNode);
            firstNode = node;

            if (lastNode == null)

                return;
        }

        if (index > 0) {

            ICharNode pred = firstNode;

            for (int k = 1; k <= index - 1; k++) {

                pred = pred.getNext();
            }

            pred.setNext(new CharNode(node.getContent(), node.getIndex(), pred
                    .getNext()));

            if (pred.getNext().getNext() == null)

                lastNode = pred.getNext();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertCharNodeAtEnd(ICharNode node) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            firstNode = node;
            lastNode = firstNode;

        }

        else {
            lastNode.setNext(node);
            lastNode = lastNode.getNext();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPalindrome() {

        ICharNode temp = firstNode;

        int count = 0;

        while (count < (length / 2)) {

            ICharNode pal = get_Symmetric(temp);

            if (pal.getContent() != temp.getContent()) {
                return false;
            } else
                count++;
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void printMessage() {
        ICharNode toPrint = firstNode;
        while (toPrint != null) {

            System.out.print(toPrint.getContent());
            // System.out.print(toPrint.getIndex());
            // System.out.print(length);
            toPrint = toPrint.getNext();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setLength(int l) {
        length = length + l;

    }

}
```

---------------Node Class--------------------

```
  package edu.wmich.cs1120.GudahWaleed.lab7.impl;

import edu.wmich.cs1120.lab7.interfaces.ICharNode;

public class CharNode implements ICharNode {

    private int index;
    private char content;
    private ICharNode next;
    private ICharNode last;

        public CharNode(char c, int i) {
            setContent(c);
            setIndex(i);
        }
        public CharNode(char c, int i, ICharNode next){
        setContent(c);
        setIndex(i);
        setNext(next);
        }

        public CharNode(){
            next = null;

        }

        @Override
        public void setContent(char c) {

        content = c;

        }

        @Override
        public char getContent() {

            return content;
        }

        @Override
        public void setIndex(int i) {

            index = i;

        }

        @Override
        public int getIndex() {

            return index;
        }

        @Override
        public void setNext(ICharNode next) {
             this.next=next;

        }

        @Override
        public ICharNode getNext() {

            return next;
        }



    }
```

-----------------------Test Class-----------------------------

```
    package edu.wmich.cs1120.GudahWaleed.lab7.impl;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import edu.wmich.cs1120.lab7.interfaces.ICharNode;
//import edu.wmich.cs1120.lab7.interfaces.IGlyphMessage;
import edu.wmich.cs1120.lab7.interfaces.IListCharNodes;
//import edu.wmich.cs1120.lab7.interfaces.IStoneAnalysis;

/**
 * @author sww
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        /*IStoneAnalysis stone = new StoneAnalysis();
        IGlyphMessage glpymsg = new GlyphMessage();
        IListCharNodes list = new ListCharNodes();

        stone.setGmsg(glpymsg);
        glpymsg.setListCharNodes(list);
        */

        IListCharNodes list = new ListCharNodes();
        ICharNode n1 = new CharNode('a',1);
        ICharNode n2 = new CharNode('b',0);
        ICharNode n3 = new CharNode('a',2);
        ICharNode n4 = new CharNode('b',-1); 

        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        System.out.print("Message 1 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        System.out.print("Message 2 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        System.out.print("Message 2.1 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        System.out.print("Message 2.2 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        System.out.print("Message 2.3 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        System.out.print("Message 3 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        System.out.print("Message 4 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        System.out.print("Message 5 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        CharNode n5 = new CharNode('c',2);
        CharNode n6 = new CharNode('a',3);

        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n6);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        list.insertCharNode(n5);
        System.out.print("Message 6 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        n5 = new CharNode('c',2);
        n6 = new CharNode('b',3);

        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n6);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        list.insertCharNode(n5);
        System.out.print("Message 7 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

    }

}
```

Comment: Is keeping an index in the node itself required for the assignment?  It seems counter-intuitive for a linked list.  For example, for indexes as a property to make sense, when a node is inserted at the front of the list, the indexes of all subsequent nodes would need to be updated.

Comment: Please post your exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
        IListCharNodes list = new ListCharNodes();
        ICharNode n1 = new CharNode('a',1);
        ICharNode n2 = new CharNode('b',0);
        ICharNode n3 = new CharNode('a',2);
        ICharNode n4 = new CharNode('b',-1); 

        list.insertCharNode(n1);
        list.insertCharNode(n4);
        list.insertCharNode(n3);
        list.insertCharNode(n2);
        System.out.print("Message 1 ");
        list.printMessage(); 
        System.out.println(" is interesting or not "+ list.isPalindrome());

        list = new ListCharNodes();
        list.insertCharNode(n4);   // Exception is thrown at this line
```

The problem is when you do

```
list = new ListCharNodes();
```

for the second time it sets lastNode field to null. Check out the constructor of ListCharNodes class.

So when insertCharNodeAtEnd is called for n4 it goes to the else part (since isEmpty yields false) where setNext method is called using null object i.e. lastNode

Hence giving a null pointer exception.